# Tkinter and reading current line from Text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have an issue where I try to read the current line as I type...Problem is the output I get is not really what it should be...

Below is the structure of the program for now.

"key_press" function is the section where the problem relies.

```
from tkinter import *
import keyword

### TEXT EDITOR WIDGET
class TextEditor(Text):

# TAGS
tags = {"int": "red"}

### Init
def __init__(self, root):
    Text.__init__(self, root)
    self.bind("<Key>", self.key_press)
    self.bind("<Button-1>", self.key_press)

### Add tags
def congif_tags(self):

    for tag, val in self.tags.items():
        self.tag_config(tag, foreground=val)

### Remove tags
def remove_tags(self, start, end):

    for tag in self.tags.keys():
        self.tag_remove(tag, start, end)

### On keyboard press event
def key_press(self, key):
    current_line = self.index(INSERT)
    current_line = current_line.split(".")
    current_line = current_line[0]

    line_break = 0

    line_text = ""

    char = self.get("%s.%d" % (current_line, line_break ))

    while char != "\n":
        line_break += 1
        char = self.get("%s.%d" % (current_line, line_break))
        line_text += char

    print(line_text)
```

Comment: "Problem is the output I get is not really what it should be...". That is always the best sort of explanation. Would you take the effort to write down what should be the output and what you received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the fact that your binding happens before Tkinter has a chance to process the event. Therefore you are always one keypress behind. Try adding your binding to a key *release*. Alternatively you can fiddle with the bind tags to arrange for your binding to fire after the default bindings.

On a slightly unrelated note: you seem to be trying to get the last character of the line. Is that correct? You can get the whole line by doing something like this:

```
line_text = self.index("insert linestart", "insert lineend")
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! I never managed to understand the index() method but I did get this to work:
line_text = self.get("{a}.0".format(a=current_line), END)